# pandas count timestamps grouped by minute

Tags: python, pandas

I have a single column series of timestamps.

```
2020-09-14 23:54:03.050
2020-09-14 23:55:05.859
2020-09-14 23:56:05.859
2020-09-14 23:57:05.858
2020-09-14 23:58:05.059
2020-09-14 23:58:05.859
2020-09-15 00:00:05.859
```

I want to group them by one minute intervals and show their counts.

```
TIMESTAMP             COUNT
2020-09-14 23:54        1
2020-09-14 23:55        1
2020-09-14 23:56        1
2020-09-14 23:57        1
2020-09-14 23:58        2
2020-09-14 23:59        0
2020-09-15 00:00        1
```

I tried the below (a whole lot of other things to be honest) but couldn't seem to get the counts.

```
data.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="1min"))
```

Help.

Comment: `df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="TIMESTAMP", freq="1min"))["TIMESTAMP"].count()`.

Comment: @HenryYik missing `key=TIMESTAMP` was my biggest mistake. if you will provide yours as an answer i will accept it as the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the key in `pd.Grouper`:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="TIMESTAMP", freq="1min"))["TIMESTAMP"].count()

TIMESTAMP
2020-09-14 23:54:00    1
2020-09-14 23:55:00    1
2020-09-14 23:56:00    1
2020-09-14 23:57:00    1
2020-09-14 23:58:00    2
2020-09-14 23:59:00    0
2020-09-15 00:00:00    1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do to_frame then we can pass the key

```
out = data.to_frame('time').groupby(pd.Grouper(key='time', freq="1min")).size()
Out[190]: 
time
2020-09-14 23:54:00    1
2020-09-14 23:55:00    1
2020-09-14 23:56:00    1
2020-09-14 23:57:00    1
2020-09-14 23:58:00    2
2020-09-14 23:59:00    0
2020-09-15 00:00:00    1
Freq: T, dtype: int64
```